# Sharepoint Cell Changed Color Code

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, shared-libraries, sharepoint-workflow

I need to be able to color code in red if any user enter to the list and changes a value, so that cell will be colored in red for a week and then once a week has passed that cell will be changed to standard black color. If that's possible?

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done this in the past is with SPDesigner and it's called conditional formatting.

There is also a how-to on [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/balsharfi/archive/2013/02/21/10282249.aspx) that might help.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The question asks if it's possible!, Me saying I have done this in the past with SPDesigner and mentioning how(Conditional formatting) should be enough to get them started. The link is merely how to.